# Large Xml in a Qtreeview

Tags: xml, qt, qtreeview

I have a large XML file (2000 -3000 lines)  that I want to go through. The purpose is to show all data in the Qtreeview and highlight those that could be wrong.

I've tested with the Qt examples (XBEL) and the one from the Jasmin Blanchette's book, but it wasn't helping me as an example (besides I'm aware that the XMLStream is not supported anymore).

What is the best way to parse and display some of the data highlighted in a Qtreeview ?
*(QTreeview is just for data interpretation in my example, I know how to handle it)*

An extract of the file to parse :

```
<Description xmlns="file://DeviceDescription-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.software.com/schemas/Description-1.0.xsd Description-1.0.xsd file://Description-1.0.xsd OEMcCustom.xsd " xmlns:se="file://Description-1.0.xsd">
  <Connector connectorId="1" explicit="false" hostpath="-1" interface="Serial" moduleType="91" role="child" alwaysmapping="true">
        <Parameter ParameterId="8000" type="std:BOOL">
            <Attributes download="false" offlineaccess="read" />
            <Default>true</Default>
            <Name>NameConfig</Name>
            <Description>Use the new NameConfig format</Description>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter ParameterId="12345692" type="localTypes:CHANNEL_PACKED">
                    <Attributes />
                    <Default>
                        <Element name="FunctionCode">3</Element>
                        <Element name="ReadOffset">16#0000</Element>
                        <Element name="ReadLength">4</Element>
                        <Element name="WriteOffset">0</Element>
                        <Element name="WriteLength">0</Element>
                        <Element name="Trigger">5</Element>
                        <Element name="CycleTime">100</Element>
                        <Element name="ErrorHandling">true</Element>
                        <Element name="EnableRegisterBitMapping" />
                    </Default>
                    <Name>Channel 1</Name>
                    <Description>ChannelConfig</Description>
                </Parameter>    
  </Connector>
</Description>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtxml/qtxml-module.html

Note the description towards the bottom of the page:

> The module is not actively maintained anymore. Please use the
>   `QXmlStreamReader` and `QXmlStreamWriter` classes in Qt Core instead.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qxmlstreamreader.html#details

It takes a while to figure this one out and use it, but it should be the fastest.  Getting all the data validation and error checking may be a little painful, but doable.

Adding it to a treeview may require some more thought... but here are some pointers:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtreeview.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpledommodel.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-xml.html

And if that still isn't enough links, here are some more:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsimplexmlnodemodel.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xmlpatterns-filetree.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: These are good pointers, especially the last 2.I have improved the question as I need more XML data interpretation code than QTreeview. The main difficulty is to intepret these examples to be able to walk through my xml example to retrieve each tags. Thanks.